# Method to count all items in Hierachical object list

Tags: c#, c#-3.0, recursion, hierarchy

I've got a simple class defined as:

```
public class MyClass
{
   //Some properties
   public List<MyClass> SubEntries { get; set; }
   //Some more properties
}
```

In another class I have a list of the above type.  At the moment, I'm having a serious mental block.  I just need to itereate through the list and count all occurances of MyClass.  Since the SubEntries property can contain 0 or more entries which can themselves contain 0 or more entries, it strikes me that I need some sort of recursice method, unless LINQ provides a mechanism to do this.

Any help releasing this mental log jam would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you allow cycles in your structure?

Comment: No, there isn't a need in this case.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Assuming you don't mind recursing down the tree, and assuming the list is always non-null and doesn't have cycles:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public List<MyClass> SubEntries { get; set; }

    public int SubEntryCount
    {
        get { return 1 + SubEntries.Sum(x => x.SubEntryCount); }
    }
}
```

You may want to rename it so that it's clear it's a *total* count of sub-entries, not just immediate children.

Comment: As always.  Thanks for a quick and useful response.

Comment: @JonSkeet Can you explain: why we  need 1+ in SubEntryCount getter?

Comment: @Jamaxack: I believe the OP wanted to include the item itself, basically. But it's hard to remember my exact reasoning from 5 1/2 years ago :)